# Remove the gray border above the arrow for Bootstrap tooltip

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, model-view-controller

Does anyone know why this thin border appears on ALL my Bootstrap tooltips? I have searched and searched and cannot find anyone else who seems to experience this. The border is there in all of our MVC projects, and we have not altered the Bootstrap CSS in any way. We are using Bootstrap 3.3.7. The image shows the thin border above the stem/arrow.
Thanks!

[image: tooltip border]

Comment: Since the line isn't there when you use out of the box BS its probably coming from another CSS file. I would look to see if there is a `tooltip-inner` class being called from somewhere else and removing that border

Comment: This question is impossible to solve without any of your code.  Use your browser's developer console to inspect the element, see if there's any `border` or `box-shadow` on the related elements, and when you find it, the developer console will even tell you which file and line number the style is coming from...

Comment: It's not a question regarding my code. It's a general question about Twitter Bootstrap. The appearance of the tooltip has the border above the arrow straight out of the box without any modifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change Css Of below classes which is use for tooltip in bootstrap.

```
.tooltip.top .tooltip-arrow,
.tooltip-inner {
    border:none;
    box-shadow:none;
    outline:none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It got me looking in the right direction. I searched thoroughly and have no custom CSS that overrides this behavior. So I modified the bootstrap.css file to correct the issue. I changed classes ".tooltip.{tooltip placement} .tooltip-arrow" by adjusting the absolute position in each of these classes by +1px. That closed the gap and hides the light colored border. Thanks for the input.

Comment: You don't need to change your bootstrap css. just add this code your custom css file with "!important". Important is give first priority to added css.

For ex : 

.tooltip.top .tooltip-arrow,
.tooltip-inner {
    border:none !important;
    box-shadow:none !important;
    outline:none !important;
}